# FadeOut function mobile issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadeout

I'm using jQuery's function to hide my header.

It's working as I like, but it has an issue on mobile devices.
The problem is: the fadeOut doesn't hide the element slowly and the function is moving the whole page 20-30 pixel higher.

This is the function:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop()>50) {
    $('.c-header').fadeOut();
  } else {
    $('.c-header').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that the value `50` should be an variable. In other words try to use values other than `50` and test it with mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fix. I just put media queries in script

```
// media query event handler
if (matchMedia) {
  var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 64em)");
  mq.addListener(WidthChange);
  WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change     window width is at least 64em
function WidthChange(mq) {
  if (mq.matches) {
     $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>50)     {
        $('.c-header').fadeOut();
     }   else     {
        $('.c-header').fadeIn();
    }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the fade transitions with every scroll change, that is many times per second while you are scrolling. Allow the fade transition only after you stop scrolling:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var me = $(this);
  var header = $('.c-header');
  var height = 50; // Might as well be header.outerHeight()
  clearTimeout(window.headerScrollTimeoutId||0);
  window.headerScrollTimeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
    if (me.scrollTop() > height) {
      header.fadeOut();
    } else {
      header.fadeIn();
    }
  }, 1);
});
```

Comment: This is not fixed the issue

Comment: @Haris. Fair enough. However the scrolling event timeout could still be applied. What you are doing in your answer with the media query is the same as in the question, but only if the window's width is less than `64em`. If you shrink the browser's window below that width, it will do nothing.

Comment: The problem was only on mobile devices. The other devices were working right. So I used Media Queries to enable fadeOut function, only to devices with 1024px and higher. That's working now.